# dataframe.replace() within a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace values in `num` column. For each letter in `ab`, I have a dictionary. I've shown only two below (A & B)

```
data = pd.DataFrame( {'ab' : ['A','B','A','A','B'], 'num' : ['01','02','01','01','01']})

a_replacements = { 'num' : { '01' : 'funny', '02' : 'serious' }}
b_replacements = { 'num' : { '01' : 'beginning', '02' : 'end' }}

data[data.ab == 'A'] = data[data.ab == 'A'].replace(inplace=True, to_replace=a_replacements)
```

The assignment in the last line works fine. But when I try to use this inside of a for loop, where I have to replaced values in `num` for 26 different letters in `ab`, I face the following issue:

```
for letter in data.ab.unique():
    data.loc[data.ab == letter] = data.replace(to_replace=letter.lower()+"_replacements")
```

To which I get:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-acd3197ceef4> in <module>()
      1 for letter in data.ab.unique():
      2     print(letter.lower()+"_replacements")
----> 3     data.loc[data.ab == letter] = data.replace(to_replace=letter.lower()+"_replacements")

/Users/alokshenoy/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-latest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace, limit, regex, method, axis)
   3427             if isinstance(to_replace, (tuple, list)):
   3428                 return _single_replace(self, to_replace, method, inplace,
-> 3429                                        limit)
   3430 
   3431             if not is_dict_like(to_replace):

/Users/alokshenoy/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-latest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _single_replace(self, to_replace, method, inplace, limit)
     70     if self.ndim != 1:
     71         raise TypeError('cannot replace {0} with method {1} on a {2}'
---> 72                         .format(to_replace, method, type(self).__name__))
     73 
     74     orig_dtype = self.dtype

TypeError: cannot replace ['a_replacements'] with method pad on a DataFrame
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Right now you're passing simply a string which corresponds to the name of the dictionary you're using to generate the mapping. Instead, use `eval` on the formatted strings directly during `replace` operation so that these expressions could be inferred correctly belonging to a `dict` object - `data.replace(to_replace=eval(letter.lower()+"_replacements"))`

Comment: This directly addresses the issue I was facing! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is in `groupby`.  This will allow you to process each group that uses unique replacements.

**Key Code:**

```
for name, group in data.groupby(['ab']):
    data[data.ab == name] = group.replace(to_replace=replacements[name])
```

**All Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'ab': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                     'num': ['01', '02', '01', '01', '01']})
print(data)

replacements = dict(
    A={'num': {'01': 'funny', '02': 'serious'}},
    B={'num': {'01': 'beginning', '02': 'end'}},
)

for name, group in data.groupby(['ab']):
    data[data.ab == name] = group.replace(to_replace=replacements[name])

print(data)
```

**Results:**

```
  ab num
0  A  01
1  B  02
2  A  01
3  A  01
4  B  01

  ab        num
0  A      funny
1  B        end
2  A      funny
3  A      funny
4  B  beginning
```

Comment: Brilliant! Didn't think of `groupby`!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply` for replace by dict of all dicts created by `zip` which map list of names in column `ab` to list of dicts:

```
a_replacements = { 'num' : { '01' : 'funny', '02' : 'serious' }}
b_replacements = { 'num' : { '01' : 'beginning', '02' : 'end' }}
abnames = ['A','B']
L = [a_replacements, b_replacements]

replacements = dict(zip(abnames, L))
print (replacements)
{'A': {'num': {'01': 'funny', '02': 'serious'}}, 
'B': {'num': {'01': 'beginning', '02': 'end'}}}

df = data.groupby('ab').apply(lambda x: x.replace(replacements[x.name]))
print (df)
  ab        num
0  A      funny
1  B        end
2  A      funny
3  A      funny
4  B  beginning
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I marked the one that was submitted before your as the answer. Nonetheless, your solution works just as effectively!